# mongodb aggregation query for field value length's sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say, I have following documents:

```
{name: 'A', fav_fruits: ['apple', 'mango', 'orange'], 'type':'test'}
{name: 'B', fav_fruits: ['apple', 'orange'], 'type':'test'}
{name: 'C', fav_fruits: ['cherry'], 'type':'test'}
```

I am trying to query to find the total count of fav_fruits field on overall documents returned by :

```
cursor = db.collection.find({'type': 'test'})
```

I am expecting output like:

```
cursor.count() = 3 // Getting
```

Without much idea of aggregate, can mongodb aggregation framework help me achieve this in any way:

```
1. sum up the lengths of all 'fav_fruits' field: 6
```

and/or

```
2. unique 'fav_fruit' field values = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'cherry']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to get just the number of fruits in the `fav_fruits` array:

```
db.fruits.aggregate([
    { $match: { type: 'test' } },
    { $unwind: "$fav_fruits" },
    { $group: { _id: "$type", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
]);
```

This will return the total number of fruits.

But if you want to get the array of unique `fav_fruits` along with the total number of elements in the `fav_fruits` field of each document, do this:

```
db.fruits.aggregate([
    { $match: { type: 'test' } },
    { $unwind: "$fav_fruits" },
    { $group: { _id: "$type", count: { $sum: 1 }, fav_fruits: { $addToSet: "$fav_fruits" } } }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your document after the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage and use the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator which return the number of items in each array. Then in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage you use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator operator to return the total count.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "type": "test" } },
    { "$project": { "count": { "$size": "$fav_fruits" } } }, 
    { "$group": { "_id": null, "total": { "$sum": "$count" } } }
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : null, "total" : 6 }
```

To get unique `fav_fruits` simply use [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

```js
> db.collection.distinct("fav_fruits", { "type": "test" } )
[ "apple", "mango", "orange", "cherry" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It may helpful to you.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $match : { type: "test" } }, {$group : { _id : null, count:{$sum:1} } }])
```